# Simulating serial port programmatically without installing driver

Tags: serial-port, driver, device, simulation, usermode

com0com is a great program to have virtual serial ports.
My question: is there any library which I can use for simulating serial ports (COM, USB and so on) programmatically in my application without install extra software for such virtual devices?

something like making virtual device in user space?
OS: Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Free Virtual Serial Ports** by **HHD Software Ltd** is good for you (License Freeware).

[image]

Excerpt:

> This device driver implements the functionality of the virtual serial
>   port device. It operates in **user mode space**, unlike most other device
>   drivers, making the system more stable and secure.

[Read more](http://www.hhdsoftware.com/free-virtual-serial-ports#ixzz21dZnpold).

Comment: how can we access this tool's dll or api reference to create port or bridge using c# app? is it possible?

Comment: Please refer to freevirtualserialports.com

Comment: You may post your comment as a question to have more attention. Be more specific.

Comment: Sorry, I'm no more active on stackoverflow (don't have time off) and more over not fluent in C#.

Comment: Ok, I've just already contact their support team and waiting for their reply. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

All similar software use a special kernel mode driver. It is not possible create a virtual COM port from user space.

Comment: It is possible. You can hook a number of things in user space and create an illusion of having a device/file/etc.

Comment: It's not possible to have the ports appear in *all* applications without a kernel driver.  Inside your own process, hooking is a viable option.